# Adding jQuery plugin to Magento 2 does not work

Tags: magento2, requirejs

I tried add [jQuery Upload File Plugin](https://github.com/hayageek/jquery-upload-file) to Magento 2 and used requirejs but it doesn't work smooth. At first time has error:

> Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function ($) {
>   "use strict";
>   /*
>       Usage Note:
>       -----------
>       Do not use both ajaxSubmit and ajaxForm on the same form.  These
>       functions are mutually exclusive.  Use ajaxSubmit if you want
>       to bind your own submit handler to the form.  For example,

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#myForm').on('submit', function(e) {
         e.preventDefault(); // <-- important
         $(this).ajaxSubmit({
             target: '#output'
         });
     });
 });
```

Use ajaxForm when you want the plugin to manage all the event binding
     for you.  For example,

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#myForm').ajaxForm({
         target: '#output'
     });
 });
```

You can also use ajaxForm with delegation (requires jQuery v1.7+), so the form does not have to exist when you invoke ajaxForm:

```
 $('#myForm').ajaxForm({
     delegation: true,
     target: '#output'
 });
```

When using ajaxForm, the ajaxSubmit function will be invoked for you at the appropriate time.

My requirejs-config.js

```
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
/*eslint no-unused-vars: 0*/

var config = {
    paths: {
        'customuploadfile' : 'Magento_Sales/js/jqueryuploadfile'
    },
    "shim": {
        'customuploadfile': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

My custom js:

```
require([
  'jquery',
  'customuploadfile'
  ], function ($,uploadFile) {
    'use strict';

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $.ajaxSetup({
        showLoader: true,
      });
      var url_anhang=$('#order_upload_anhang').val();
      var anhang_uploadObj;
      anhang_uploadObj = $("#anhanguploader").uploadFile({
        url:url_anhang,
        formData:{ form_key: FORM_KEY,order_id:$('#add_anhang_to_order').attr('value')},
        fileName:"file",
        cancelStr:"x",
        autoSubmit:false,
        dragDropStr : false,
        showProgress:true,
        showDone:false,
        showAbort:false,
        onSuccess:function(files,data,xhr)
        {
          var url=$('#order_anhang_save').val();
          var order_id=$('#add_anhang_to_order').attr('value');
          anhang_uploadObj.reset();
          var aj = new Ajax.Request(
            url, {
              method:'get',
              parameters:{
                "order_id" : order_id,
                "data" : data
              },
              onComplete: function (text)
              {
                $.get(window.location.pathname, function( data ) {
                  $('.anhang_show').html(jQuery(data).find('.anhang_show').html());
                });
              }
            }  
          );
        },
      });
      $(document).on( 'click', '#add_anhang_to_order',function(){
        anhang_uploadObj.startUpload();
      });
    });
```

If reload page it work but sometime has error, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

magento 2 already add "jquery/file-uploader" lib ready for use
Why do you need another one?

In your js code just require it

```
require(['jquery',"jquery/file-uploader"], function() {
  // Write your logic here
});
```

You can see more jquery plugins in `lib` folder in root directory